# Use Groovy to Sort XML File

Tags: sorting, groovy

Is there a way I can sort an xml file base on certain attributes with Groovy?

Here's my xml

```
<List>
    <Person name="fff"/>
    <Person name="ggg">
        <PhoneNum>
            <AreaCode>555</AreaCode>
            <Number>1234567</Number>
        </PhoneNum>
    </Person>
    <Person name="eee"/>
    <Person name="ccc"/>
    <Person name="jjj"/>
    <Person name="ddd">
        <PhoneNum>
            <AreaCode>555</AreaCode>
            <Number>7654321</Number>
        </PhoneNum>
    </Person>
    <Person name="aaa"/>
    <Person name="bbb"/>
    <Person name="ttt"/>
</List>
```

and I want the output to be

```
<List>
    <Person name="aaa"/>
    <Person name="bbb"/>
    <Person name="ccc"/>
    <Person name="ddd">
        <PhoneNum>
            <AreaCode>555</AreaCode>
            <Number>7654321</Number>
        </PhoneNum>
    </Person>
    <Person name="eee"/>
    <Person name="fff"/>
    <Person name="ggg">
        <PhoneNum>
            <AreaCode>555</AreaCode>
            <Number>1234567</Number>
        </PhoneNum>
    </Person>
    <Person name="jjj"/>
    <Person name="ttt"/>
</List>
```

I've looked into XMLSlurper but I can't quite seem to figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a modification to @dmahapatro's answer that preserves the nested node structure.

```
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder

String xml = '''
<List>
    <Person name="fff"/>
    <Person name="ggg">
        <PhoneNum>
            <AreaCode>555</AreaCode>
            <Number>1234567</Number>
        </PhoneNum>
    </Person>
    <Person name="eee"/>
    <Person name="ccc"/>
    <Person name="jjj"/>
    <Person name="ddd">
        <PhoneNum>
            <AreaCode>555</AreaCode>
            <Number>7654321</Number>
        </PhoneNum>
    </Person>
    <Person name="aaa"/>
    <Person name="bbb"/>
    <Person name="ttt"/>
</List>
'''

def rootNode = new XmlParser().parseText(xml)
rootNode.children().sort(true) {it.attribute('name')}
new XmlNodePrinter().print(rootNode)
```

Here's what's going on:

- Using `XmlParser` instead of `XmlSlurper` generates nodes that can be printed using `XmlNodePrinter`.
- The children of the node are sorted by name using `sort {it.attribute('name')}`
- The `true` attribute to sort mutates the underlying list, which reorders the child nodes.
- The `XmlNodePrinter` prints the re-sorted xml document to standard out.

Answer (score 1):

I think there can be a groovier way than this. But this should work on a Friday. :-)

```
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder

def xml = '''<List>
    <Person name="fff"/>
    <Person name="eee"/>
    <Person name="ccc"/>
    <Person name="jjj"/>
    <Person name="aaa"/>
    <Person name="bbb"/>
    <Person name="ttt"/>
</List>'''

def rootNode = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)

def writer = new StringWriter()
def mkp = new MarkupBuilder(writer)
mkp.List{
    rootNode.Person.@name.list()*.toString().sort().each{
        Person(name: it)
    }
}

println writer
```

Comment: Is there a way to make that work while retaining child elements of the elements that are to be sorted? I'll add an edit to my question so you can see